# subsetting dataframes based on column values in r

Tags: r, dataframe

Given a dataframe ex:

```
a <- c(1:3,4:6)
b <- c(2:4,3,2,1)
c <- cbind(a,b)
```

i would like to subset dataframe by removing rows with similar comparison (ex: row3: 3,4 is same as row4: 4,3) and have only one of them.

Comment: `c` is a function in R and should never be used as a variable name.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried thus far?  This is a fairly basic question that has probably been answered before.  You'll find you get much better answers if you not only give some data, but also share the steps you've taken toward solving the problem on your own.

Comment: Sorry. My dataframe is huge (90M rows). I used the following steps to subset the dataframe.

Comment: @dayne, I agree with your comment, but `df` is also a function name, as is `data` and many other names that are commonly used as variables. To my knowledge, all the answers here would work whether the object is named "c" or your other favorite letter of the alphabet. That said, Ram should heed your warning if only because by using "c", he will also be making his code less readable.

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestions. I will stop using function name as variable name in my R scripts.

Answer (score 3):

```
a <- c(1:3,4:6)
b <- c(2:4,3,2,1)
d <- cbind(a,b)
e <- t(apply(d,1,function(x){x[order(x)]}))
d <- d[!duplicated(e),]

> d
     a b
[1,] 1 2
[2,] 2 3
[3,] 3 4
[4,] 5 2
[5,] 6 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `d` is your matrix, not `c`:

```
e <- unique(apply(d,1,function(x) paste(sort(x),collapse="~")))
> t(sapply(strsplit(e,"~"),as.numeric))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    2    3
[3,]    3    4
[4,]    2    5
[5,]    1    6
```

Breaking it down:

**First line**

`apply(d,1,function(x) ... )` takes each row of d and passes it as a vector `x` to the anonymous function whose body I've called `...` here.

The function body is `paste(sort(x),collapse="~")`, which sorts the vector and then turns it into a length-one vector with each element separated by a `~`.

So the `apply` call overall is going to return a character vector where each element used to be a row of the matrix.

Then `unique` keeps only the unique elements.  The sorting ensures that this does what we want it to.

**Second line**

`strsplit(e,"~")` splits our character vector back into a separated form.  In this case, it's a list where each element is a character vector of the numbers that comprise each row.

`sapply(...,as.numeric)` applies `as.numeric()` to each element of the list.  So we convert the character vector back to a numeric vector.  Since the `s` in `sapply` stands for "simplify," it will create a matrix from this.

But it's the wrong direction (2x5 instead of 5x2)!  `t()` transposes the matrix to the original form.

Comment: +1 but you should really explain what this does step by step because it is probably not obvious for someone who's not very familiar with R

Comment: Just a (possibly) minor thing. This works but does change the order of a and b if a>b... which may be unwanted.

Comment: You're right.  It also assumes everything's numeric.  To avoid the first problem, you can use `!duplicated` instead of `unique` (because then you can use the logical vector to select out of the original matrix).  I believe this is what @dayne's solution now does.

Comment: @nico Went and step-by-stepped it.

Answer (score 1):

in your example, c is not a data.frame but a matrix. c shouldn't be used as variable name, as other stated.

in one line, you can do:

```
a <- c(1:3,4:6)
b <- c(2:4,3,2,1)
cc <- cbind(a,b)
cc[!duplicated(t(apply(cc,1,sort))), ]
     a b
[1,] 1 2
[2,] 2 3
[3,] 3 4
[4,] 5 2
[5,] 6 1
```